# Setting up developer workstation for LAMP and SVN environment

Tags: svn, lamp

We are a software developement team with 60 web developers. 
We have our developerment environment deployed on LAMP servers. And we use
VSS as our source control. All of us are having windows7 workstations and 
we use tools like secureFX, putty to connect to our sevrers.
Webserver(apache), source code(PHP), databases(MySQL) are all located on our
developement server.
Now we are planning to move to SVN source code repository.

1. Problem is how we can setup each developers workstation(windows7) with 
   local copy of Linux(redhat), source code, web server, DBs(database size is very big say more than 100GB) to 
   decentralize the developement environment.
2. Each developer will be working on multiple releases, which inturn require many databases to be placed on developer machine.

Please let me know if any standard methods are used to make such setups and how can we go about it.

Comment: Your explanation is not clear to me. Is the source code now in windows or linux ? what do you mean by "local copy or linux" ? are you intending to setup wamp ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way will be to leave Linux out the mix for development environment. Apache HTTP server with PHP support and MySQL can be installed on Windows itself. Have a central SVN. Let each user have their own checked out copy of source code. Deploy it on local Apache, running against local DB. Once unit tested, they can check in the code into SVN. You can also convert your Linux server into a continuous integration machine or build machine or you can use it for QA.

Comment: IF you are going to develop on windows locally and then deploy to linux you definitely want to have that middle step to build and test on linux whether you just deploy to a linux box and manually run tests/QA or whether you use a CI to automate build/test and then QA... I dunno what youre going to do about the massive DB size though I suppose you could setup MySQL to have it data directory on a network share...

Comment: One probability is that, may be that much of data is not needed during development and with careful look at the app, a required subset of DB could be extracted for development.

Comment: @krishna: very true.. a specialized fixture for local unit/functional tests would suffice i think. then when they deploy to QA they can have the full data there to make sure they dont nuke anything.

Comment: We can not switch our development to WAMP, as many things will not work in WAMP. We need to carry our developement in LAMP. On our windows desktops we need to put LAMP setup.

Comment: What exactly do you expect to fail in WAMP? I think those will be minor tweaks, as much as I can understand.

Answer (score 1):

Erasing windows, dual booting or virtual linux?

Installing linux, svn, and pulling your source code are relatively trivial.  You should be able to setup a relatively unassisted bash script for this, or give instructions for your developers to follow.  Another option is creating an image with all the generic programs pre-installed.  The size of the database is the big problem.

1)  Try to shrink the DB.
2)  If it's still extremely large, then make several copies on external hard drives and pass them around.  I prefer this to network copy, as it's likely faster, less error prone, and doesn't bring your network to a crawl.

That takes care of setting up the initial machines.  For future development, try to limit which developers work on which databases to minimize the necessity to copy.  Exactly how you implement this will depend on your project specifics.  Also, consider having developers work with only a subset of the data; perhaps they don't need the full 100G to develop/maintain code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This solution looks more closer to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use Virtual box and run LAMP inside it. I have not tried it though. You may still need to trim your DB to be as small as possible. I would do this only if I am entirely convinced that it is not possible by just using a Windows box.

http://blog.quibb.org/2010/02/setting-up-a-virtualbox-lamp-server/

http://www.virtualbox.org/

Also, I am assuming that you wish to continue using Windows at the same time. If that is not a criteria, you could try dual boot of windows and linux.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I am looking into this option. let me setup a virtual box and check our application.